# Installing a C# library in Visual Studio and using it on unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit of a noob on that topic so I'm searching for help. I need to install this library (https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp) for a unity project where I need to check phone numbers.
But as I always made simple games in unity I really don't know how to do that and I don't really know either what to search to find an answer.

If anyone of you knows how to do it, it will really make my day.
Thank you

Comment: unity manual provides infos about how to use DLL's https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at this, but my main concern is that in the lib I want to use I don't know where is the dll file, I have found some dll but with weird name that don't seems to be what I want.

Comment: looking at the readme from the git, it seems like you have to build it yourself

Comment: yes that's where I'm stucked, I've installed the two .Net package that he says are necesary but I don't know where to type the command :

xcopy "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\$(dotnet --version)\Microsoft\Portable\" /S /E

I've never done nor used those kind of things.

I've also try launching a build from PhoneNumbers.csproj, I saw it had created some PhoneNumbers.dll at multiple place, but I don't know witch one I need to use.

Comment: okay so I run the command xcopy..... in powershell as administrator and it seems to have worked at least it has done something but I don't know what.
I have PhoneNumbers.dll in all of those versions `net35;net40;net46;netstandard1.3;netstandard2.0;portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8`
I've tried putting some of the those dll in unity but appart of adding the .dll file in the project explorer, I don't see his scripts, nor I can use them in code.
I'm really sorry to bother you, but I'm completely lost

Comment: depending on your project you can use [different .net versions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/overview-of-dot-net-in-unity.html).
to use the classes of the dll you have to  use `using DLLname;` in your script

Comment: the problem is that `using PhoneNumbers` is not recognize in my code and is returning this error : `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PhoneNumbers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
And I've tried with all PhoneNumbers.dll files that I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once do a build on a project you want to use in Unity, then find the DLL output from the build. I recommend you do Release Builds, but for now if you are not familiar with Visual Studio just use what you were able to build. If there are multiple directories then you only need one - the best one to use would be any labelled ".NET Standard" which it seems you have a .net standard 2.0 directory.
Go to your Unity project in the Assets folder, and if there isn't already a Plugins folder create one. Then in Assets/Plugins create a folder named whatever you want for the library - in this case PhoneNumber would be fine. So you would have Assets/Plugins/PhoneNumber and you would copy/paste the contents of your NetStandard2 folder there.
In the end you should have Assets/Plugins/PhoneNumber/PhoneNumber.dll

As soon as you have that dll, you can switch back to Unity and see if it worked by checking the Unity Console for any Errors. You might receive errors saying it could not load the DLL. Almost always if it can not load the DLL it is because of missing dependent DLLs - which is why I said to copy the entire folder contents inside the "NetStandard2" folder since it may contain more than just PhoneNumber.dll - it may have it's necessary dependent dlls also.

If not, you can read the error output and hopefully get a clue as to what dependent dlls are missing. You can also expand the Dependencies in Visual Studio.
Typically the DLL failing to be loaded in Unity is because of missing dependent DLLs. Expanding the Dependencies, which is found under the project name in the Solution Explorer window on the right side of Visual Studio, will show you what libraries it requires. Most of what you see under dependencies (if not all) will require a similarly named dll. Under the netstandard2.0 dependency I see System.Collections.Immutable - so you may need a System.Collections.Immutable.dll which should (usually) be in the output folder when you build the project. You would also need that dll in Unity in your PhoneNumber folder along with PhoneNumber.dll

Comment: So after building the project, I as you said put everything that was in NetStandard2 in my Assets/Plugins/PhoneNumbers folder but it still wouldn't work. In the NetStandard2 there is only the PhoneNumbers.dll  1 .pdb and 1 .xml. So I searched in the other version and found that in Net46 I had : PhoneNumbers.dll, System.Buffers.dll, System.Collection.Immutable.dll, System.Memory.dll and System.Runtime.CompileServices.Unsafe.dll . So I've pasted all of them in my Assets/Plugins/PhoneNumbers, but still I can't acces it in my code, and I don't have any error so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Small update, I've moved the PhoneNumbers folder out of Assets/Plugins and put it directly into the Assets folder and now I can finally put "using PhoneNumbers;" without any problem, it is recognize. The problem that I have now is that it seems that I can only acces PhoneNumberType enum of PhoneNumbers, but not all the other method that I need.